# Using Directory Roles for authorization in ASP.NET MVC application using AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-active-directory

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 app which depends on multi-tenant authentication using Azure Active Directory. I have authorization setup globally by adding AuthorizeAttribute filter. Now I want the app to be accessible only by users who belong to particular **Directory Roles** (Global Administrators and User Administrators to be specific). What is the best way to enforce this?

Roles in the principal only contains app specific roles. I was hoping that one of the identity claims would certify standard directory roles. But only claim that is relevant is the "groups" claim that tells me what Directory Roles AND Application Groups the user belongs to. I then need to query each group object ID to see if one of them is a Directory Role I want to allow.

Also, is there a way to do this globally by adding it as a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varun, in the coming weeks we are planning to add a new claim in the token that contains the well-known identifiers of the directory roles that the user belongs to. [Stay tuned](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/) for that.

Until then the best option is to query the Graph API at login, d[etermine the directory roles the user belongs to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151667.aspx), and inject claims of type role in the claims principal. This will enable an authorize attribute filter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Dushyant. It certainly helps. But is there a definitive way to say that a group is one of the well known Directory Roles when I make graph call and get the details of the group? I don't want to solely rely on name of the group being "User Administrator" or such.

Comment: Yes, you can use the well-known identifier of the directoryRole. e.g. company admin = "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10", user account admin = "fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1"

Comment: Please post an updated answer on new changes, as this one says "in progress" from 2015.